# Complex hierarchy - show selected object in outliner

Tags: parent, outliner

I have a file with assets that we bought for some game. They are organized in "groups" - parented to empty objects. There are many many of these "groups" with another "groups" inside of them. How do I find where the object is?

Fastest way I found is to select all the elements by hand in viewport and then in outliner use Search - Selected, unparent objects so they're outside of groups.

Clicking all the elements by hand is the main issue though. I'd like to select a building for example, and have it automatically selected in outliner so it's easy to select other elements grouped with it in outliner instead of selecting in viewport.

Photoshop does what I like - when object I click is in group, Layers panel opens this group and focuses view on that object layer. It should be like that in Blender imo. :< Any plugin for that or simple workaround?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is already selected in the Outliner when you select an object in the viewport. You can press <kbd>Numpad .</kbd> to show active while you hover your mouse over the Outliner.